# Is this 3NF decomposition done right?

Tags: database-normalization, functional-dependencies, 3nf

> The relation R(ABCDEF) is given with the following functional dependencies:
>
> ```
> A->B
> B->C
> A->D
> A->E,F
> E->F
> ```
>
> State the strongest normal form this is in and then convert it into third normal form.

I think the relation is in first normal form since there exists a partial dependency while the candidate key is A. Therefore to convert it into second/third normal form I decomposed R(ABCDEF) into

```
R1(A,B,D,E,F) 
R2(B,C) 
R3(E,F)
```

Aren't all these in third normal form? Have I done the decomposition right?

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went wrong (or right). See hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: PS  "with the following FDs"--That is not enough to answer the question. You need to know that the FD set is a cover; you need to know *all* FDs that hold. "since there exists a partial FD while the CK is A"--That is not sound. The definition of 2NF involves *certain* partial FDs & *certain* attributes & CKs are involved in a *certain way*. "the relation is in 1NF"--You mean, it has 1NF as its "strongest NF"; any relation in xNF fo x>=1 is in 1NF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A schema is not in 2NF when a non-prime attribute is depending from a proper subset of a candidate key (the so-called partial dependency) (see for instance [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form)). Since in your schema the only candidate key is `A`, this is not possible, so the schema is in 2NF.

Your decomposition in 3NF is not correct, since in the relation `R1(A B D E F)` the dependency `E->F` holds, with the attribute `F` not prime and non-trivially depending on an determinant which is not superkey.

A correct decomposition is:

```
R1(A B D E)
R2(B C)
R3(E F)
```

Note that in the case of your decomposition, `R3` is contained in `R1`, which is not possible.

Comment: Hilariously, now the English phrasing you happen to have chosen, which is not just giving the definition directly, is ambiguous!--do we read "(X is not in 2NF) when (...)" or "X is not (in 2NF when ...)--where that latter reading makes one ask, well when *is* it in 2NF? (The former is presumably intended. The latter is equivalent to a certain implication.) Natural language is so slippery! (I normally use "when" for "if and only if" to not alienate non-math folk ... maybe now I need to stick to "exactly when" ...? No, that wouldn't this time anyway ... Nor "iff" ....) But here I'll bow out.

Comment: @philipxy , you are so right about the slippery of the language (and more so for a non-native speaker!). Feel free to edit the post, I throw the towel!